# "System.FormatException" when getting user input from console - visual c#

Tags: c#, console-application

I am trying to make a command line program that will ask if fast and long you want it to beep. I keep getting `System.FormatException` on the code below. I get the problem right after `Console.WriteLine("how many times should i beep?");`. I've found a fix by putting a `console.read();//pause` right after this line.

My question is what am I doing wrong? or am I suppose to have the pause after that line?

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("how fast would you like the sounds to play?");
        Console.WriteLine("70 = fast and 300 = slow can pick any number inbetween");
        string choice = Console.ReadLine();
        int speed = Convert.ToInt32(choice);
        Console.Write(speed);
        Console.Read();//pause
        Console.WriteLine("how many times should i beep?");
        string choice2 = Console.ReadLine();
        int j = Convert.ToInt32(choice2);
        Console.Write(j);
        Console.Read();//pause
        for (int i = 0 ; i < j; i++)
        {
            Console.Beep(1000, speed);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

My psychic debugging skills tell me that it's this line throwing the exception:

```
int j = Convert.ToInt32(choice2);
```

Putting the `Console.Read()` in like you mentioned before that causes that line not to execute immediately and delaying the throwing of the exception.

If you input something that isn't an integer on this line:

```
string choice2 = Console.ReadLine();
```

You will get a `FormatException` on the following `Convert.ToInt32` call.

See the [documentation for `Convert.ToInt32`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sf1aw27b.aspx) where it tells you a `FormatException` is thrown when the value you pass `does not consist of an optional sign followed by a sequence of digits (0 through 9).`

To solve your issue, use [`Int32.TryParse`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f02979c7.aspx) (or just make sure you enter a valid integer). That will return a boolean indicating the success or failure of the parsing rather than throwing an exception.

Also, welcome to StackOverflow! Be sure to upvote answers you find helpful and accept the one that best resolves your question.

Comment: It's an odd policy IMO, but the guy can't upvote answers with just 6 rep. I struggled with that for a while myself.

Comment: @KevinT Strange, I never knew that. Oh well

Answer (score 3):

why are those extra `Console.Read()` in there? They are breaking your program, because the user will press `return` too many times

```
    Console.WriteLine("how fast would you like the sounds to play?");
    Console.WriteLine("70 = fast and 300 = slow can pick any number inbetween");
    string choice = Console.ReadLine();
    int speed = Convert.ToInt32(choice);
    Console.WriteLine(speed);
    Console.WriteLine("how many times should i beep?");
    string choice2 = Console.ReadLine();
    int j = Convert.ToInt32(choice2);
    Console.Write(j);
    for (int i = 0; i < j; i++)
    {
        Console.Beep(1000, speed);
    }
```

Comment: Kinda sorta. Though you're correct, the cause of the exception is bad user input... which could very well be because of having to press return so many times and likely causing them to enter an empty string for the one `ReadLine` that actually matters.

Comment: I tested this quickly. It's as if the return press for the `Read()` call gets passed right into the `ReadLine()` call, so it immediately tries to parse an empty string. It's kinda bizarre behavior.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, all you need to do is remove those `Read()` pauses you threw in. I'd probably also change the `Write()` calls to `WriteLine()` calls.

You can also change the `Read()` calls to `ReadLine()` calls, if you insist on "pausing" there.

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
    Console.Read();
    string choice2 = Console.ReadLine();
```